# Transaction ID for Authnet CIM Transaction

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have successful CIM transactions using profileTransAuthCapture, however
I cannot find in the docs if it returns a transaction id. I printed out the response, but I did not see one. In the direct Response there is a long string with random strings in, I'm not sure if one of those is it. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the seventh field in that string. To get it just do the following:

```
$response = explode(',', '1,1,1,This transaction has been approved.,S7GS9X,Y,2195560752,INV000001,description of transaction,10.95,CC,auth_capture,876571,John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Townsville,NJ,12345,,800-555-1234,,user@example.com,John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Townsville,NJ,12345,,1.00,,2.00,FALSE,PONUM000001,209D159CA9DB7377279D33A6A9E9678E,P,2,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX1111,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,18272830,100.0.0.1');
$transactionID = $response[6];
echo $transactionID;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.org/OIn3JUFu)

Comment: Is this really the best way of doing this?